# App Service Plan storage increase - Azure

Tags: azure

I am learning Azure and I have a question about App Service Plans.
I understand that an App Service Plan has an amount of RAM memory for each virtual machine instance. However, when it comes to storage space, I have a doubt if every time we create a virtual machine instance it is consuming disk space in the plan. For example, I have an application that consumes 1GB with a VM instance. If we scale out this plan and create 3 VM instances, will it take up 3GB of disk space? I understand the instances as copies of the content of the Plan, therefore I understand that for each instance the disk space consumption is multiplied by two. Is that so?

Thank you very much for your responses,

All the best.

Comment: are you using app services or vms ?

Comment: @Thomas I am using app services

Comment: if you have multiple app service (or scale out) in the same app service plan, they will share the resources.

Comment: @Thomas Yes I know that but my question is about VM instances. If I have one VM instance in an App Service Plan and I scale out and create one more instance: the disk space consumption is multiplied by two? My 1GB app with one instance now Does it occupy 2 GB in the plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

From Azure's own description of its plans, I conclude that each Plan provides ACU, RAM and disk space FOR EACH INSTANCE, not for the total plan.

In the example in the image, each instance has 210 ACUs, 3.5GB of memory and 250GB of storage.

App Service Plan P1V2:

[image: App Service Plan P1V2]